# Where to download .ADM or .ADMX file to setup default search providers within Windows 2008 R2 for Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer, google, search-engine

Where to download .ADM or .ADMX file to setup default search providers within Windows 2008 R2 for Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://www.bibble-it.com/2010/05/18/vista-windows-7-custom-google-search-engine-policy-ie7-ie8) is one of the better resources I've come across. It provides a great overview, downloadable ADMX and ADML files, as well as what's required to properly implement them through a GPO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @jscott I completely agree, and don't want to post links just for the sake of it, but the question asked where he can go to download the AMDX files. Unless StackExchange is able to host files, but even then, I'd still like to properly give credit to the blog's author.

Comment: @jscott What Matt said, plus that blog post is way too long to CnP into a SF Answer. He did at least explain what he's linking to...

Answer (score -1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=16f69ffe-d51b-4e02-9d02-3e57f3ccd490

Administrative Templates found there.  .ADMX have replaced .ADM in 2008.

2008 only: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=927FC7E3-853C-410A-ACB5-9062C76142FA&displaylang=en